# How to call a list of items from a text file

Tags: batch-file

I'm using a tool called Benzin; everyday I have to write a new command for the new files I'm dealing with. I would like to create a text file that has a list of the files I need. Then, look through the list of files and use Benzin on them. Benzin is used as follows:

```
Benzin R filename.brlyt filename.xmlyt
```

I'd like the tool to automatically look through the list and then replace "filename.brlyt" with what's written inside the text file and convert the files one by one.

Sadly I don't know how to do this so I thought of doing another thing, I just simply place the files inside a folder and do this command:

```
FOR /D %%A IN ("Files\*.brlyt") Do Benzin.exe R %%A %%A.xmlyt
pause
cls
rename *.brlyt.xmlyt *.xmlyt
pause
```

That is giving file not found error, can anyone see what's wrong?

Ok, so I've found the code

```
    @echo off
for /f %%A in (files.txt) do (
echo converting
echo %%A
benzin r %%A coverted/%%A.xmlyt
pause
cls
)
pause
rename *.brlyt.xmlyt *.xmlyt
pause
```

How do I make another batch that writes the list of files in a directory into the text files.txt? Here's what I'm trying but it is only showing me "\files\" inside the text file.

```
@echo off
FOR /D %%A in (\files\) Do (
echo writing %%A into files.txt
echo %%A > files.txt
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('TYPE test_list.txt') DO ECHO %%A
PAUSE
```

Now, looking at, we see: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/servers_nt.txt

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('TYPE %~dpn0.srv ^| FIND /V ";" ^| SORT') DO CALL :ChkSrv %%A
GOTO End
```

I would use/re-use that for your code.